# Srcset for responsive images in cloudinary

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I am trying to make my images responsive. I want to use the image with 300 width with any viewport below 768px and 1000 width with any viewport above 768px. I have tried playing around with the max-width properties etc, but they make no sense.

```
<img srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/w_300,f_auto,q_auto,c_scale/v16242113131341/pc-template10_bzbdfk.webp 768w,  
             https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/w_900,q_auto,c_scale/v1624131231341/pc-template10_bzbdfk.webp 900w"    
             src='https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/q_auto,c_scale/v1624131231341/pc-template10_bzbdfk.webp' alt="PC" class="pctemplateforvideo" />
```

Comment: Even I have this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to define the `sizes` attribute. Please check Mozilla's [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#how_do_you_create_responsive_images), which provide an excellent explanation

Secondly, if you want to have a lo-res image up-to 768px, as best practice it's recommend to provide 768px as well, this to avoid upscaling the image.
Here's the sample code of what it would look like:

```
<img srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/w_300,f_auto,q_auto,c_scale/v16242113131341/sample 300w,  
             https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/w_900,q_auto,c_scale/v1624131231341/sample 900w"
     sizes="(max-width: 768px) 300px,
            900px"
     src='https://res.cloudinary.com/xxx/image/upload/w_900,q_auto,c_scale/v1624131231341/sample' alt="PC" class="pctemplateforvideo" />
```